# Why can't interfaces in Java 8 have private or protected fields?

Tags: java, java-8, access-modifiers

I created a simple interface in Java 8 to test out what can be done with default methods:

```
public interface MyInterface {

    public String name = "";

    default public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I tried making `name` private, then protected, and both gave me compiler errors stating that "only public, static & final are permitted".

So I have two closely-related questions which may or may not have the same answer:

Why can't fields in an interface have the private modifier?

Why can't fields in an interface have the protected modifier?

Comment: Note that all fields declared in interfaces are implicitly `static` and `final`.

Comment: Why do you want non public static final fields in interfaces anyway? It looks to me that you misunderstand the primary purposes of interfaces.

Comment: I'm looking at whether interfaces are useful for approximating multiple inheritance with the addition of default methods. Which, it seems, they're not. @SotiriosDelimanolis, that note is really the answer to my question.

Comment: @MartinCarney you can have multiple inheritance of behaviour (via default methods) but not of state (via instance fields).

Comment: @assylias oh? Well, why not... If it is planned that it is possible then there must be a good use case for it, yet I fail to see one... Would that only be for default methods?

Comment: @fge sorry I got mixed up - private methods will be allowed in interfaces https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8071453

Comment: not the same but It's not impossible to have instance state http://ideone.com/3kTKkO - realistically, maybe applicable to something like http://ideone.com/Xlk9db

Comment: @zapl: `darkSecret` is a funny name for a `public` field…

Comment: @Holger Are you against transparency? The public needs to know :)

Comment: @zapl: as a side note, you can do something similar in a non-`public` fashion by putting the `static` variables in a different class within the same package. Neither that helper class nor its variables need to be `public`…